# How to forward the client certificate in spring cloud gateway?

Tags: java, spring-boot, x509, spring-cloud-gateway

I have a SSL enabled spring boot REST app. I have to use spring cloud gateway to access the service.

Whenever I send a request along with client certificate, SCG strips down the certificates before and sends to the micro-service.

I am wondering if there is a way to configure SCG not to alter anything in the client's request and just forward the request & certificates to the correct route? (all i need SCG is to route to the correct endpoints)

Comment: How do you send a client certificate? If you use X.509, then it's normal it is being stripped on the HTTP endpoint.

Comment: @cezaryButler yes, i am using x.509 certificates, is there a way to make SCG to not strip down anything and pass it as it is? (I am very new to SSL and SCG)

Comment: I'll need some time to look into that. The question is whether the certificate is used to sign the payload and whether is being sent using some kind of header (probably Authorization)? Can you supply me with sample request (including headers)? Can you supply me with sample traffic?

Comment: When a TCP connection breaks the SSL certificate gets terminated (offloaded) and won't be possible to forward the same certificate to the downstream server. As it brings main in middle attack. To achieve the same you need layer 4 (transport layer) gateway. Using Nginx Stream it is possible to implement, but not using Spring Cloud Gateway.